# display particular image associated with tag

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I'm new with wordpress and I tried to look for an answer but everything I found and tried didn't work. So let's start from the beginning I added this code to functions.php in my child theme:

```
function wptp_add_tags_to_attachments() {         
  register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'attachment' );
}
add_action( 'init' , 'wptp_add_tags_to_attachments' );
```

Now I can add tags to images in admin section. 
The problem is that I want to display those images on post and category page next to the tags assigned to the post at the bottom where they appear in default. I added the category to the main navigation so after I click on it a page with all the post excerpts in the category are displayed. And at the bottom are shown tags associated with given post.

An example cause I'm not sure I explained it so that it's easy to understand.

I have 3 posts: project1, project2 and project3 which are in category Projects. Every one of those three projects has assigned one or more of these tags: company1, company2, company3. For every company tag there is an image with the same company tag assigned to an image (logo of the company). And I want to display not only the tag name but also the image associated with the tag.

Is there some way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code snippet which I found [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags):

```
<?php
  $posttags = get_the_tags();
  if ($posttags) {
    foreach($posttags as $tag) {
      echo '<img src="http://example.com/images/' . $tag->term_id .  '.jpg" 
            alt="' . $tag->name . '" />'; 
    }
  }
?>
```

So the final product is this:

```
<?php
$posttags = get_the_tags();
$templPath = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/images/';
if ($posttags) {
  foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    $html = '<div class="projectLinkWrap">';
    $html .=  '<a href="'. get_the_permalink() .'#projectpartner"/>';
    $html .= '<div class="thumbLogoWrapper">';
    $html .= '<img src="'.$templPath . $tag->name.'.png" 
    alt="' . $tag->name . '" /></div>';
    $html .= '<span class="tagName">'. $tag->name .'</span></a></div>';
    echo $html;
  }
}
?>
```

Hope it helps someone one day.